# How to run a .NET program, automatically, every hour

Tags: .net, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have xml data I access through a web service. I need to read the data and copy it locally. The below code works fine. I need now to run this code at least twice or three times a day wihout manual intervention. How do I do that? Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;


 class MainClass{
public static void Main(){
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
// read
doc.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(GetContracts()));

// write
XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter( "testOut.xml", null );
tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
tw.Indentation = 4;
doc.Save( tw );
tw.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: The fact that you are writing XML has nothing to do with the root of the question, which is... *how can I run an application every hour?*  The question is better asked on superuser.com or serverfault.com  .

Comment: sorry, but I had read about Timer Controls in vb.net which set a time interval to execute an event and thought that maybe here I could get more information about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Task Scheduler. There's a GUI and a Command Line interface to set up tasks.
If you use the GUI, find it in Start....Control Panel....Administrative Tools... on Vista.   You'll be able to figure out how to run your think hourly, pretty easily.

[image]

if you use the command line, check the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357(VS.85).aspx

```
schtasks.exe /create /tn "My Task" 
            /tr "C:\path\to\the\app.EXE arg1 arg2" 
            /sc DAILY /RI HOURLY  
            /st 12:00:00 /ru username /rp password
```

(The above should be all-on-one-line)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you want the scheduling to be done.  If it is only a few times a day, I would just schedule the application to be executed on a regular basis using the Task Scheduler within Windows.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. If I want this update to be done hourly, for example, how should it be done?

Comment: Even hourly, you can setup via Task Scheduler.

Answer (score -1):

Quartz is a good scheduler for java, of course you will either need to setup the jar to start with windows or install on an application server like Tomcat or Jetty.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/