# write a program which runs in background and perform actions every hour

Tags: c#, windows, background

I would like to write an application in C# which runs in the background most of the time. It should only show a TrayIcon. For this I found a tutorial: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/creating-tray-applications-in-.net-a-practical-guide/

But how can I tell my program to run every hour? Whats the best way to implement this. A timer? The app should use as less as possible resources while doing nothing.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a .NET program, automatically, every hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421252/how-to-run-a-net-program-automatically-every-hour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question: is the program you're doing a "user space" program, or should it run even if a user is not logged in? In other words, should it always be on?

Basically, are you doing something useful to a user, or is this for a business task like archiving a web server's log files to database?

If it's the former, keep doing your notification area program. If it's the latter, skip the notification area program and build a full-out [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28VS.80%29.aspx).

In both cases, use a timer; resource use will be minimal.

Comment: Yes it should run always and react on user log-ins.

Can I use the .Net Timer class for the timer?

Comment: What do you mean by reacting on user logins? I realize you may not want to divulge everything, but what are you trying to do, exactly? **Edit** Also, your windows service should be able to detect logins by overriding [OnSessionChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onsessionchange.aspx)

Comment: I need to write a program that gain all information about a computer like cpu model, ram, graphic.... and it should log user log-ins and user log-outs. It also should be possible to let the user create a message in the app.

Comment: Hmm... Ok, you've got quite a list of functionality there. I think everything in your first sentence can probably be handled by a Windows Service with an override of OnSessionChange. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353066/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-detect-logon-logoff-and-switch-user-events) for additional info. But your second sentence causes problems... Windows Services typically don't have a user interface. You may want to have a *second* Notification Area program that only handles user messages.

Answer (score 8):

Don't have a program that runs all the time but only performs activity every hour. Write a program that performs the activity and then schedule it hourly using [Task Scheduler in windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

Comment: Exactly what I was going to propose

Comment: It has the added advantage that your application doesn't consume any resources while it's not performing the activity as it's not actually running during that time.

Comment: but the application should give the user the possibility to interact with it. and the application should react on changes in the file system or when a user is logging on or off

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the processing cost, but you could code in a sleep timer to put it to sleep for an hour in a loop so it will wake up, run, then sleep again.  Not sure of the drain on resources when sleeping though.  Also, if the program might take a few minutes, you could calculate sleep time based on the DateTime.Now DateTime object so it wakes up every hour on the hour.